# How to change backGround color in Xamarin forms NavigationPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to change the background color of navigationBar in navigationPage I'm using this code:

```
using System;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace P
{
public class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
 MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
    }
    protected override void OnStart ()
    {
    }
    protected override void OnSleep ()
    {
    }
    protected override void OnResume ()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
   }
  }
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just set the BarBackgroundColor property of the NavigationPage instance:

```
new NavigationPage(new LoginPage()) { BarBackgroundColor = Color.Green };
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to setup a global style in xaml, you could something similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Sample.App">
    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
                <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="#ff5733"/>
                <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: @x-rw Difficult to say without much information.  Did you include this in your app.xml file?  If still a problem, I suggest opening a separate question.

Comment: Awesome! This works without all kinds of customizations

Answer (score 1):

```
<Application.Resources>
    
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!--Global Styles-->
        <Color x:Key="NavigationPrimary">Green</Color>
        <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
            <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
            <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

1. basically go to App.xaml
2. paste this code there
3. change the colour however u want in this part
   **Green**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the NavigationBar BackgroundColor on each page with a different color. You can do the following on the Codebehinds of each page/view.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace NewApp.Cross.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NewView : ContentPage
    {
        public NewView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Title = "PageTitle"

            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);

            ((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black;
            ((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarTextColor = Color.OrangeRed;
        }
    }
}
```

It works on Android and iOS.